# React Native Firebase/Functions throwing Error: UNAUTHENTICATED

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-functions, react-native-firebase

I have a Google Cloud Function deployed successfully.  It works in the browser, but when I try to call it from my React Native project using React Native Firebase, I get a console warning: "Possible unhandled promise rejection (id: 0): Error: UNAUTHENTICATED".  My function code is:

```
// functions/index.js

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {OpenAI} = require('openai');

async function determineBrandFromModelNumber(modelNumber) {
  const openai = new OpenAI({apiKey: OPENAI_API_KEY});
  const completion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
    model: 'gpt-4',
    // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
    messages: [{role: 'user', content: `Determine the brand of the tool with model number: ${modelNumber}`}],
  });
  console.log(completion.choices[0].message.content);
  return extractBrandInfo(completion.choices[0].message.content.toLowerCase());
}

function extractBrandInfo(text) {
  console.log('TEXT: ', text);
  switch (true) {
    case (text.includes('dewalt')):
      console.log('HIT');
      return 'dewalt';
    case (text.includes('stanley')):
      return 'stanley';
  }
}

exports.determineBrand = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  if (!context.auth) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError('unauthenticated', 'Endpoint requires authentication!');
  } else {
    return determineBrandFromModelNumber(data.modelNumber);
  }
});
```

And I call it here:

```
const handleSavePress = async () => {
    const { data } = await firebase.functions().httpsCallable('determineBrand')(
      {
        modelNumber: modelNo,
      },
    );
    console.log('DATA: ', data);
    const tool: Tool = {
      tid: generateUUID(15),
      modelNum: modelNo ? modelNo : '',
      serialNum: serialNo ? serialNo : '',
      name: toolName,
      imageUris: photos ? photos : [],
      owner: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
      createdAt: new Date().getTime(),
      updatedAt: new Date().getTime(),
    };
    console.log('TOOL: ', tool);
    handleCreateTool(tool);
    navigation.goBack();
  };
```

When I try to call the handleSavePress() method, I get the unauthenticated warning, but no errors, but none of the console.log statements after the firebase.functions() call get executed, nor does handleCreateTool(tool) or navigation.goBack(), so it's getting hung up somewhere in the firebase.functions() call.  None of the console.log statements within the functions/index.js get executed either.

I have allAuthenticatedUsers set as Cloud Function Invoker in permissions.  I also tried setting it as Firebase Viewer per another question here, but that didn't work either.

I am new to Google Cloud Functions, and any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding allUsers to the Cloud Functions Invoker permission.